# Read line by line from text file and save each line to different cell in array

Tags: java

I'm trying to split each line from a text file into cells in an Array. Can I do it with split function and not count the lines in order to create an array?

I am using `Scanner` for reading files from Scanner. The file contains in each line the following format: `number_number`
I want to save `number_number` as a string into a cell in Array.
However, I don't know how many lines in my text file could be, in order to set an array size. I don`t want to use`LinkedList`, please use the assumption that will not have many lines.
Is it possible to read from file and save each line into cell in array?
There is no problem to change the method from Scanner to another one.

The problem in my code currently that it saves only the first line in my file.

```java
public String[] readFromFileToStringArray(String s) {
        Scanner scanner = null;
        try {
            scanner = new Scanner(new File(s));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String[] fileText = null;
        if (scanner != null)
            while (scanner.hasNext())
                fileText = scanner.nextLine().split("\n");
            return fileText;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `scanner.nextLine()` you read the text until the `\n` character, so the split you did is pointless since the line string won't have this character.

You can read all the file and then split it:

```java
public String[] readFromFileToStringArray(String s) {
    String text = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(s)), 
 StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    return text.split("\n");
}
```

But really as the other answered said, it would probably be better to simply use `List`

Answer (score 0):

Should you change the way to add string to the array?

```java
fileText.add(scanner.nextLine());
```

OR:

```java
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(fileText));
list.addAll(Arrays.asList(scanner.nextLine().splite("\n")));
String[] fileText = list.toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(pathToFile);
```

java Files is the easiest way for this.